# Android, Junit and testPreconditions()

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

I'm trying to do some tests on my application's database.
I only got one activity in my application ("Home") so my test class is
public class HomeTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {..}

My troubles :

1) In Android developers I've seen that testPreconditions() method is supposed to be launch before all tests, but in my app, it's acting like a normal test ...

2) I'd like to fill my database before all other tests to begin. But to do so, I need a reference on my Activity, but I can't call "this.getActivity" in the tests constructor ...
Is there a way to do something after the constructor ?
(The setUp() method isn't appropriate, because it is called before each test, not just one time before all)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The order in which the test are run is **not guaranteed** to run before other tests, as junit 3 uses reflection to find the tests.
2. Use the `setUp()` method, this also assure that your tests run with a fresh database

Comment: Ok for the 1) !
For the 2), I needed a method that is launched just one time before all tests, but I finaly changed my way of testing ... Thanks !

Comment: You may add a variable to make it run once only?