# Strange NullPointerException at Android SpinnerActivityTest

Tags: android, junit, android-testing

I was lately working with the Activity Testing Tutorial on androids developer site. By following the step-by-step guide up to Adding UI tests - 1. you get this code snippet:

```
  package com.android.example.spinner.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

import com.android.example.spinner.SpinnerActivity;

public class SpinnerActivityTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SpinnerActivity> {

    private SpinnerActivity mActivity;
    private Spinner mSpinner;
    private SpinnerAdapter mPlanetData;
    public static final int ADAPTER_COUNT = 9;
    public static final int INITIAL_POSITION = 0;

    public SpinnerActivityTest() {
        super("com.android.example.spinner", SpinnerActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
        mActivity = getActivity();
        mSpinner = (Spinner) mActivity
                .findViewById(com.android.example.spinner.R.id.Spinner01);
        mPlanetData = mSpinner.getAdapter();

    }

    public void testPreConditions() {
        assertTrue(mSpinner.getOnItemSelectedListener() != null);
        assertTrue(mPlanetData != null);
        assertEquals(mPlanetData.getCount(), ADAPTER_COUNT);
    }

    public void testSpinnerUI() {
        System.out.println("testSpinnerUI(): mSpinner = " + mSpinner);

        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("run(): mSpinner = " + mSpinner);
                mSpinner.requestFocus();
                mSpinner.setSelection(INITIAL_POSITION);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can this be?

Some facts I already figured out:

1. It doesn't happen when you debug the TestApplication (even without breakpoints)
2. It doesn't happen when you send the UI Thread to sleep for some millis
3. When you log mSpinner directly before mActivity.runOnUiThread() it is NEVER null (even when you get the NullPointerException) but indeed when you log it in the Runnable.

//EDIT: Added System.outs + stacktrace:

```
07-30 19:20:08.001: INFO/ActivityManager(1362): Displayed com.android.example.spinner/.SpinnerActivity: +118ms
07-30 19:20:08.011: INFO/System.out(3180): testSpinnerUI(): mSpinner = android.widget.Spinner@40525150
07-30 19:20:08.071: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3180): GC_EXPLICIT freed 45K, 49% free 2754K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 44ms
07-30 19:20:08.071: INFO/System.out(3180): run(): mSpinner = null
07-30 19:20:08.081: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3180): Shutting down VM
07-30 19:20:08.081: WARN/dalvikvm(3180): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at com.android.example.spinner.test.SpinnerActivityTest$1.run(SpinnerActivityTest.java:46)
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-30 19:20:08.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 19:20:08.121: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3180): GC_EXPLICIT freed 18K, 49% free 2756K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 43ms
07-30 19:20:08.131: WARN/ActivityManager(1362): Error in app com.android.example.spinner running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.android.example.spinner.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}:
07-30 19:20:08.131: WARN/ActivityManager(1362):   java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 19:20:08.131: WARN/ActivityManager(1362):   java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: include the stack trace.

Comment: Sounds like some concurrency issues, i.e. `mSpinner` disappears by the time `run()` gets to it.  Maybe try something with [wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) and [notify()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) to make sure that `testSpinnerUI()` function does not return until the Runnable completes?

Comment: I included the stack trace. @ikh I can make it work with waiting time, etc. It's more about knowing WHY it sometimes does not work with the my approach.

Comment: Probably due to testPreConditions() call, try commenting it out and see if it change anything. More discussion in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867112/android-junit-and-testpreconditions).